# Conjecture about the transitive closure of a relation $\mathcal R $ over a finite set $A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, examples-counterexamples, relations, function-and-relation-composition

Given a binary relation $\mathcal R$ over a set $A$,then the transitive closure of $\mathcal R$ over $A$ is the smallest transitive relation on $A$ containing $\mathcal R$, it's indeed the intersection of all transitive relations over $A$ that are a superset of $\mathcal R$.

The transitive closure of $\mathcal R$ is denoted by $\mathcal R^{+}$ and has the following explicit formula:
$$\mathcal R^{+}=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathcal R^n$$

Where $\mathcal R^1=\mathcal R$, and

$\mathcal R^{n+1}=\mathcal R^n ∘ \mathcal R^1\tag{$n \in \mathbb N^+$}$

---

The first time I faced the formula I thought that it is not practically applicable,since it's needed to take the union of infinitely many relations (with infinity many distinct relations).

However after working with some sets I realized that it's not generally true,for example let $\mathcal R$ be a set over $A=\left\{1,2,3\right\}$ defined as $$\mathcal R:=\left\{(3,2),(2,3)\right\}$$
Then one can prove by induction that $$\mathcal R^{2n}=\left\{(3,3),(2,2)\right\}=\text{id}_A \setminus \left\{(1,1)\right\}\;,\;\mathcal R^{2n-1}=\left\{(3,2),(2,3)\right\}=\mathcal R\tag{$n \in \mathbb N^{+}$}$$

So the transitive closure of $\mathcal R$ over $A$ is given by:

$$\mathcal R^{+}=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathcal R^n=\left[\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathcal R^{2n-1}\right]\cup \left[\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathcal R^{2n}\right]  $$
$$=\mathcal R \; \cup \text{id}_A \setminus \left\{(1,1)\right\}=\left\{(3,2),(2,3),(3,3),(2,2)\right\}$$

I computed the transitive closure of $\mathcal R$ over a few sets,and all of them had such a pattern,neither of them needed the union of an infinite number of infinity many distinct relation to be taken.

The questions are :

- Is this true that to determine the transitive closure of a relation $\mathcal R $ over a finite set $A$, we **always** just need to take the union of infinite number of finitely many distinct relations on $A$?
- If no,then give a counterexample, if yes then please prove it.

Comment: Note that every relation over $A$ is a subset of $A\times A$ and there are $2^{|A|\times |A|}$ possible such subsets.  As such, there are finitely many possible distinct relations over $A$.

Comment: I don't understand... why do you not believe that $\mathcal{R}^n$ is a relation over $A$?  That should be obvious...  Indeed, if $S$ and $T$ are both relations over $A$, we have that $S\circ T = \{(a,c)\in A\times A~:~\exists b~(a,b)\in S,(b,c)\in T\}$ which is obviously a subset of $A\times A$... just look at the first part where we note that $(a,c)\in A\times A$.  That is... a composition of relations is another relation.

Answer (score 2):

It helps to understand intuitively what the transitive closure does at each step.
Suppose $A$ is a set, and we have a relation $R$ on $A$. Then, for any $n\geq1$, the relation $aR^nb$ says that there exist $x_1,\dots,x_n$ such that $aRx_1$, $x_nRb$, and $x_iRx_{i+1}$ for all $i$.

Formally, the transitive closure $R^+ := \bigcup_{n\geq1}R^n$ is given so that $aR^+b$ if $aR^nb$ for some $n\geq1$; that is, $a$ is related to $b$ in the transitive closure of $R$ iff we can connect $a$ to $b$ through finitely many $x_1,\dots,x_n$ such that $aRx_1$, $x_nRb$, and $x_iRx_{i+1}$ for *some* $n$.

If we truncate the union and consider $R^{\leq N} := \bigcup_{n=1}^NR^n$, we get a similar relation, except that $aR^{\leq N}b$ iff we can connect $a$ to $b$ through **at most $N$** intermediate $x_1,\dots,x_n$ (that is, $n\leq N$).

Now, in the case that $A$ is finite, let $N := |A|$, then it turns out that $R^+ = R^{\leq  N}$ (that is, you only need to take a finite union $\bigcup_{n=1}^{|A|}R^n$ to obtain the transitive closure)! To see this, suppose $aR^+b$, so $a$ is related to $b$ in the transitive closure of $R$. Connect $a$ to $b$ via $x_1,\dots,x_n$.

- if $n\leq N$, then this means $aR^{\leq N}b$ and there is nothing to do
- otherwise, $n>N$, meaning that there are more $x_i$'s than there are elements of $A$ (since $|A|=N$). By the pigeonhole principle, we will have for some $i<j$ that $x_i=x_j$. Therefore, we can shorten our chain $aRx_1Rx_2\dots x_nRb$ by removing the terms $x_{i+1},\dots,x_j$. This produces a strictly shorter chain $x_1,\dots,x_i,x_{j+1},\dots,x_n$ connecting $a$ to $b$. Inductively, we can repeat this process until the length of the chain is $\leq N$, showing that $aR^{\leq N}b$ as before.

Therefore, you're right: if $A$ is a finite set, then we need only take the union up to $N := |A|$ (in fact, it is enough to take the union up to $|A|-1$) to form the transitive closure.
Why is the transitive closure defined with an *infinite* union then? This is because we may need to take an *arbitrarily large* (albeit still finite) union to obtain the transitive closure. To see this, just consider the set $A = \{1,\dots,N\}$ and the relation $R$ defined by saying $iR(i+1)$ for all $1\leq i<N$. Taking the transitive closure of $R$ will require at least $N-1$ iterations of the union to ensure that $1$ gets related to $N$.

Moreover, the reason that we take an infinite union in the definition is because it continues to work even if $A$ is infinite. If $A$ is an infinite set and $R$ is some relation on $A$, you can check that $R^+ := \bigcup_{n\geq1}R^n$ will in fact be the **smallest** transitive relation containing $R$ (transitivity is easy to see by using the interpretation of $R^+$ provided in the second paragraph).

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ be a set with $n$ elements. Let $a, b \in A$ such that $a \mathcal{R}^{+} b$. Then there is a $k$ and there are are $c_{i} \in A$, for $i = 1, 2, \dots, k$, such that
$$
\tag{chain}
a \mathcal{R} c_{1} \mathcal{R} c_{2} \mathcal{R} \dots \mathcal{R} c_{k} \mathcal{R} b.$$
Suppose further that $k$ is smallest such that (chain) holds.

If $c_{i} = c_{j}$ for some $i < j$, we also have
$a \mathcal{R} c_{1} \mathcal{R} \dots \mathcal{R} c_{i}  \mathcal{R} c_{j+1}  \mathcal{R} \dots \mathcal{R} b$, a  shorter chain. (The same holds if $a = c_{i}$ or $c_{i} = b$ for some $i$.) Therefore we may assume that in (chain) $a, b$ and the $c_{i}$ are distinct. It follows that $k \le n - 2$, so that
$$
\mathcal{R}^{+}
=
\bigcup_{i=1}^{n-1} \mathcal{R}^{i}.
$$

Comment: @45465 while true that $\mathcal{R}^+$ is as you say, we don't need nearly as large of an upper bound on $n$ as you suggest.  As Andreas' answer already points out you can have a *much* smaller upper bound.  Of course, both being finite, either would successfully prove what you originally wanted.